# Convert this expression from Linq.IQueryable to Linq.ParalellQuery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-4.0

I'm by far not a LINQ master, but I'm getting into some complex queries now that I've rolled my Data Access Layer into Entity Framework 4. The following is the SQL I have converted into LINQ

```
select DISTINCT DegreeCategories.CategoryTitle 
from DegreeCategories

inner join Degrees on DegreeCategories.DegreeCategoryID = Degrees.DegreeCategoryDegreeCategoryID
inner join Programs on Programs.DegreesDegreeID = Degrees.DegreeID
inner join ProgramCategories on Programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID = ProgramCategories.CategoryID
inner join OccuPathBridge on OccuPathBridge.ProgramCategoryID = ProgramCategories.CategoryID
inner join CareerMap on OccuPathBridge.OccupationID = CareerMap.OccupationID

where Programs.DegreesDegreeID in ( 
            select Degrees.DegreeID from Degrees where Programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID in
                ( select ProgramCategories.CategoryID from ProgramCategories where CategoryID in 
                    ( select OccuPathBridge.ProgramCategoryID from OccuPathBridge where OccuPathBridge.OccupationID in
                        (select OccupationID from CareerMap where CareerMap.OccupationTitle = 'Pharmacists')
                    )
                )
            )
```

The Linq as best I can tell is 1:1 - however the containing type does not contain a method for "Contains()" which is causing the expression to fail all together.

```
(from degreecategories in db.DegreeCategories
join degrees in db.Degrees on new { DegreeCategoryID = degreecategories.DegreeCategoryID } equals new { DegreeCategoryID = degrees.DegreeCategoryDegreeCategoryID }
join programs in db.Programs on new { DegreesDegreeID = degrees.DegreeID } equals new { DegreesDegreeID = programs.DegreesDegreeID }
join programcategories in db.ProgramCategories on new { ProgramCategoriesCategoryID = (Int32)programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID } equals new { ProgramCategoriesCategoryID = programcategories.CategoryID }
join occupathbridges in db.OccuPathBridges on new { ProgramCategoryID = programcategories.CategoryID } equals new { ProgramCategoryID = (Int32)occupathbridges.ProgramCategoryID }
join careermaps in db.CareerMaps on occupathbridges.OccupationID equals careermaps.OccupationID
where
    (from degrees0 in db.Degrees
    where

        (from programcategories0 in db.ProgramCategories
        where

            (from occupathbridges0 in db.OccuPathBridges
            where

                (from careermaps0 in db.CareerMaps
                where
                  careermaps0.OccupationTitle == "Pharmacists"
                select new {
                  careermaps0.OccupationID
                }).Contains(new { occupathbridges0.OccupationID })
            select new {
              occupathbridges0.ProgramCategoryID
            }).Contains(new { ProgramCategoryID = (Int32?)programcategories0.CategoryID })
        select new {
          programcategories0.CategoryID
        }).Contains(new { CategoryID = (Int32)programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID })
    select new {
      degrees0.DegreeID
    }).Contains(new { programs.DegreesDegreeID })
select new {
  degreecategories.CategoryTitle
}).Distinct()
```

Where do I begin to start translating this query into a Parallel Query?

I've included all the requisite includes

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;
using MyProjects.DAL;
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've used Linqer, Linqpad, and several tutorials out there on google to try and write sub-select based queries. none of which have yielded any results.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to re-write the SQL query to be somewhat sane before converting it? A lot of those joins seem to be unnecessary (hint: if you have `DISTINCT` in your query, chances are >80% that you've written it wrong)

Comment: Its all in how these database tables are presented. I don't think the normalization of the database ever got out of 2NF. I'm having to traverse all of these tables to get at the data i want because there's no direct link between the occupation titles and the Degree Category. While i realize this is bad form - its the parameters in which I have to operate. In a perfect world and all that... I'd redesign the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As just one example of what's wrong with the *SQL* version, we have this:

```
 in ( 
        select Degrees.DegreeID from Degrees where Programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID in
```

Since the `WHERE` clause here isn't referencing the `Degrees` table at all, that's effectively selecting all rows from that table. So, it seems to be a null operation.

Can you confirm if the following query gives equivalent results:

```
select DISTINCT DegreeCategories.CategoryTitle 
from DegreeCategories

inner join Degrees on DegreeCategories.DegreeCategoryID = Degrees.DegreeCategoryDegreeCategoryID
inner join Programs on Programs.DegreesDegreeID = Degrees.DegreeID
inner join ProgramCategories on Programs.ProgramCategoriesCategoryID = ProgramCategories.CategoryID
inner join OccuPathBridge on OccuPathBridge.ProgramCategoryID = ProgramCategories.CategoryID
inner join CareerMap on OccuPathBridge.OccupationID = CareerMap.OccupationID
where CareerMap.OccupationTitle = 'Pharmacists'
```

Then we can look at converting it to an EF/LINQ query.

Comment: You sir.. are doing it right. That gave me the exact same result.

Comment: @lazyPower - Hopefully you can convert to linq without our help from that starting point. I CWed this "answer" since it wasn't an actual answer to your question as posed (but I needed more space for formatting than a comment affords).

Comment: Crying shame, your solution is more elegant than what I was asking for. I'm always on the look out for when I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write `db.DegreeCategories.AsEnumerable()`